# Temporarily ban an ip address using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ip-address

Is there a way to temporarily ban (only for 5-10 minutes) a certain ip address using `.htaccess`.

Comment: Sure, remove it after 5-10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a cron job that updates the htaccess file on a regular interval (5-10 mins if you want).

Comment: And more importantly, a good reason to do this in an automated manner.

Comment: Really any script would do, doesn't have to be a cron job... but the question of why one would do such a thing with `.htacess` seems like the more pressing question to me.

Comment: maybe he doesn't have full access to the system ?

Comment: You can create .htaccess files through php...